# Anime with a floating city, a boy and his girlfriend

Tags: story-identification, anime

In this anime I saw (it's been years), it seemed like a nice floating city, but something was going on (sadly don't know the exact plot anymore), so the main character gets somehow chased by the police and falls off the city with this girl he met and as he wakes up from his fall he gets cared by an old man, and it turns out people who live down there need to be careful because the city sends out drones to check on them, also they are searching for the boy.
I think the girl had some weird powers but not sure.

Also I recall them later being up on the floating city again but in the underground and he tries to get something done there, it's really futuristic down there (just dark and some guidelights which are stripes of light). But this part **could also be** from a **different anime**, it's been too long.

The boy should have given the girl to the police because of whatever she could do but refused, that's why both got chased. Maybe also because of something else but I think this was the main reason.

It's a series, not a game or anime movie. It seemed not like a new one, it could be about 5-10 years old or so. Also it's sadly not a really known one, I searched already in forums.

([Someone on MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1165301) also seems to be searching for the exact same as far as I can tell)

Comment: From the title I would have guessed Castle in the Sky, but the description doesn't fit: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092067/

Comment: Floating city? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Angel_Alita

Comment: Floating city? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daphne_in_the_Brilliant_Blue

Comment: Floating city, girl with weird powers? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTzYHqCfekk

Comment: Floating city, world is a garbage dump (not an anime but a video game with cut-scenes); https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deponia_(video_game)

Comment: Romeo x Juliet has a floating city and a tournament; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Gl2mwIqP14

Comment: I think I just saw something very like this listed on Netflix.

Comment: @Thomas no i have seen castle in the sky, also it's not an anime-like movie but for sure an anime series

Comment: @Valorum it's non of them, it's also a series, no game or movie

Comment: It looks like the pitch for Astro Boy, the movie of 2009 (floating city, underground action,...) but I am not sure. Maybe the previous Astro Boy series fit better ?

Comment: Can you describe the fundamentals of the floating city?  How was it suspended and how was it connected, physically, with the regular ground?  Visuals like this in fantasy are usually retained best and more helpful in determining which movie.

Comment: @Mikey it wasn't connected to the ground, it was floating, sadly i don't know what the power source was... also it was up hiiigh in the sky, so the boy technically would have died but didn't

Comment: @Goufalite nah sadly not Astro Boy :/

Comment: Kaiba, perhaps?

Comment: @Fhnuzoag nah also not kaiba... didn't really have unique art style

Comment: "Floating city" is ambiguous. I suppose you mean a city floating on the ocean, but in science fiction and fantasy a "floating city" could also be a city floating in the air. You should clarify this.

Comment: @user14111 - "*it was up hiiigh in the sky*"

Comment: @Thomas I think Yakki's description [closely matches](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/269122/31393) *Laputa: Castle in the Sky*, with maybe two points of disagreement.

Answer (score 9):

That does sound like [Ergo Proxy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0791205/).

It is from 2006. The anime is about a society where people live together with androids. The story follows a female inspector who investigates a series of murder.

I recalled the scene you mentioned when the protagonist falls down the floating city.

After his fall he gets nursed by an old man living in some kind of dumpster village. There they have to hide from drones sent by the authorities of the floating city. I only remember the plot up to this point, so I cannot say anything about a return to the floating city.

Comment: Can you provide a synopsis and possibly some more details that suggest similarity between the two, maybe you could add an image of the cover or something? Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9445/68872) and see if you can add some good details.

Answer (score 1):

Try [*Patema Inverted*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/12477/Sakasama_no_Patema) (*Sakasama no Patema*).

> Patema is a plucky young girl from an underground civilization
> boasting an incredible network of tunnels. Inspired by a friend that
> mysteriously went missing, she is often reprimanded due to her
> constant excursions of these tunnels due to her royal status. After
> she enters what is known as the "forbidden zone," she accidentally
> falls into a giant bottomless pit after being startled by a strange
> creature.
>
> Finding herself on the surface, a world literally turned upside down,
> she begins falling towards the sky only to be saved by Age, a
> discontented student of the totalitarian nation known as Aiga. The
> people of Aiga are taught to believe that "Inverts," like Patema, are
> sinners that will be "swallowed by the sky," but Age has resisted this
> propaganda and decides to protect his new friend. A chance meeting
> between two curious teenagers leads to an exploration of two unique
> worlds as they begin working together to unveil the secrets of their
> origins in Sakasama no Patema, a heart-warming film about overcoming
> differences in order to coexist.

Comment: Could you explain why you think this fits?

Answer (score 1):

I think it likely you are recalling [*Laputa: Castle in the Sky*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_in_the_Sky) produced by Studio Ghibli and directed by [Hayao Miyazaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayao_Miyazaki).

Let's go through what you remember:

- **In this anime:** Check! Anime.
- **it's been years:** Check! *Laputa* came out in 1986.
- **it seemed like a nice floating city:** Check! Nice floating city-sized castle (see image below).
- **something was going on:** Check! Secret plots and a few factions competing to access the floating city.
- **the main character gets somehow chased by the police:** Both the main characters (the girl Sheeta, and the boy Pazu) are chased by military police, specifically because of a pendant Sheeta carries, and because of her genetics and knowledge of 'spells' important in Laputa.
- **and falls off the city with this girl he met:** Various falls occur by both characters throughout the film, including from flying heights.
- **as he wakes up from his fall he gets cared by an old man:** Sheeta and Pazu fall into a deep mining hole, and are cared for by an old man (see picture below). The old man has insights about the deep earth that are connected to the power source for Laputa.
- **it turns out people who live down there need to be careful because the city sends out drones to check on them:** Semi-check. There are robot drones (see image below) that occasionally come to earth from Laputa, but they are mostly oriented towards protecting Sheeta either because of a pendant she carries (you can see in the movie poster below), or because of her ancestry (descended from the ancient Laputan rulers), or both.
- **also [the drones] are searching for the boy:** Either a misremembering, or you are not recalling *Laputa*, as the robots were not pursuing Pazu, *per se*.
- **I think the girl had some weird powers:** The pendant she wears and ger genetics give her unusual abilities (floating to ground, glowing, as in the movie poster below, and interfacing with the control centers of Laputa… she also was taught 'spells' which are commands for the Laputan control centers).
- **Also I recall them later being up on the floating city again but in the underground and he tries to get something done there, it's really futuristic down there (just dark and some guidelights which are stripes of light).:** CHECK! This very much describes the climactic scene.
- **It's a series, not a game or anime movie.:** Either a misremembering, or you are not recalling *Laputa*

Image of part of Laputa:
[image: View of Laputa from above]

Movie poster for *Laputa: Castle in the Sky*:
[image: Laputa: Castle in the Sky movie poster]

Here's is a picture of the old man who helped them after they fell into a deep mining hole:
[image: Movie still 1]

Here is a picture of one of the robot drones (they are ancient, and in various states of repair from very good condition, to kinda broken, to completely defunct). This one lives in a garden in Laputa, and has plants growing on it (some also have animals living on them!). The robot drones' arms can also spread and serve as wings, their eyes shoot lasers, etc.
[image: Robot drone from Laputa]

'Underground' portions of the city in the sky:
[image: Movie still 2] [image: Movie still 3]

Answer (score 0):

The anime I think you are thinking of is [Children of the Whales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_the_Whales)

> The story focuses on a boy called Chakuro, who lives on a giant vessel
> called a Mud Whale that drifts over the sea of sand. In the Mud Whale,
> society is divided into two kinds of people: the Marked, who can move
> objects with their minds using a strange power called "thymia", at the
> expense of shortened lifespans, and the Unmarked, people who lack
> thymia but enjoy longer lifespans. Chakuro and his friends have never
> seen anyone from the outside world, and they spend their days yearning
> to explore and learn about it. In year 93 of the vessel's exile, the
> Mud Whale encounters a lonely island and Chakuro finds a girl inside,
> starting an adventure that changes the lives of everyone.

I had to google it myself to find it but this sounds closest to what you are asking for.

Comment: Could you [edit] in any explanation as to why you think this is what the OP is looking for?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is terse; could you [edit] in the elements that make you think this is the answer and how it matches the asker's description? This would make for a better answer; you might want to read [answer].